# Looping through an object in localStorage to append the object's values to a table, but it says my values are undefined

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage, javascript-objects

So I'm storing some information for a table in localStorage. The information looks like this:

`localStorage = Storage {Mon Jan 04 2021 14:53:49: "{"duration":"00:00:16","reason":"test1"}"}`

I've set up the beginnings of a table in my HTML and now I'm trying to append the above information to the table looping through every object.  I made it work before, but the way I did it wasn't very readable so I am trying to condense it using loops.  But now my code keeps throwing the error:
"displayRecords.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined"

This is my code:

```
var row = document.createElement('tr') 
//function to loop through localStorage and append data to table
function appendRowsloop() {
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage['length']; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i)
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage[key])
    [key, obj.duration, obj.reason].forEach(function(element) {
      var node = document.createTextNode(element)
      var tData = document.createElement('td')
      tData.append(node)
      row.append(tData)
    })
  }
  document.querySelector('table').append(row)
}

appendRowsloop()
```

It's throwing the error at line: `[key, obj.duration, obj.reason].forEach(function(element) {`

I've tried changing my code various amounts of times, but I always come back with the same error.  It worked when I only used one for loop, but it was very reptitive with lots of variables defined for a one time use like this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage['length']; i++) {
  var key = localStorage.key(i)
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage[key])

  var node1 = document.createTextNode(key)
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(obj['duration'])
  var node3 = document.createTextNode(obj['reason'])

  var table = document.querySelector('table')


  var row = document.createElement('tr')
  var keyData = document.createElement('td')
  var duration = document.createElement('td')
  var reason = document.createElement('td')

  keyData.append(node1)
  duration.append(node2)
  reason.append(node3)
  row.append(keyData)
  row.append(duration)
  row.append(reason)
  table.append(row)
}
```

I know the above code is super repetitive, hence why I was trying to rewrite it.  Or is that code acceptable?

Comment: You don't have any variable named `row` in your code. Please add it, since I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Row is now defined above the function, I forgot to hit enter after the code formatting, sorry

Comment: Your "messy" code is actually far more readable than the new code. I would stick with that if it was working.

Comment: I guess messy maybe isn't the right word for it, but I thought that continually defining variables with things like var1, var2, var3, ect, is a sign that there is a better way to do things, that's why I was trying to make it into something iterable.

Comment: It turns out I was missing a ; , putting the semicolon corrected the error.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a value stored in `localStorage` that doesn't conform to your expected shape. Open DevTools and inspect your stored data or use `console.log(localStorage[key])` and make sure everything looks as you would expect:
[image].

Comment: Thanks, I did that several times in the console with my localStorage, and every time the result was what I was expecting.  I'll add what I did before that worked, but that I'm trying to improve.